# Do I need to set a proxy for every package in CygWin

Tags: angularjs, node.js, proxy, cygwin

I am behind a company firewall.
I am creating a new AngularJS/Cordova project in Cygwin on my Windows laptop.

I have configured a proxy for CygWin :

```
export http_proxy=http://url:portno
export https_proxy=https://url:portno
```

I need to install npm, bower, cordova, grunt etc.

Do I need to configure a proxy for each of these packages also?

Also by running this command does it permanently configure the proxy for CygWin or do I need to run this command everytime I need to install something?

Comment: Why not just ask IT to allow access to the resources you require?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is : once I have a proxy configured for CygWin, does it get implemented for every package that gets installed with CygWin e.g. npm